# Is there a way to save MSG files from an Outlook PST file without changing the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME value?

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-redemption

I am using Redemption to save individual messages from a PST file to MSG files. Today I discovered that this sets the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME value in the saved MSG file to the date and time the message was saved. This is undesirable because we do not obtain the MAPI property values until after the MSG file is saved, so we are getting incorrect data. Is there any way to save the MSG file without overwriting this property as it existed for the message prior to saving to file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not - PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME is a calculated property and is set by MAPI when the message is modified.

If you only need to read the last modification time of the original message, you can open the message using RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile and save the value of the PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME in your own named property.